# Given the surface, find a point $(a,b,c)$ with $c>0$, which has a maximum distance from the plane $z=0$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, maxima-minima, surfaces

> Given this surface: $x^2+y^2+z^2+xz-1=0$. 
> find a point $(a,b,c)$ with $c>0$, such that it's distance from the plane $z=0$ is maximal.

**My attempt**:
The Plan: 
writing the distance from the point $(a,b,c)$ to the plane $z=0$ as a function, and finding the maximum value, and making sure it's on the given surface. 

Distance from a point $(a,b,c)$ to $z=0$ : $|c|=c \Rightarrow$    (since $c>0$)
I'm really not sure how to continue, I don't know what next step I should do, I thought of substituting $c$ in the main function, but, what do I get from that? how to I find $a,b$? I'm basically stuck here. 
Any help is really appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Use Lagrange multipliers to find the maximum value or $f(x,y,z)=z$ subject to the constraints $g(x,y,z)=1,z>0$ where $$g(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2+xz$$ I did it quick, but I'm getting a maximum distance of $\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The surface is given by $x^2+y^2+z^2+xz-1=0$. As you rightly said the distance from a point $(a, b, c)$ on the surface to plane $z = 0$ is $|c|$. So the distance is maximum when $|c|$ is maximum, with the given constraint $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ca - 1 = 0$. We only need to consider $c \gt 0$. Applying Lagrange Multiplier method,

$c = \lambda (a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ca - 1)$ and differentiating we get the following set of equations,

$ (2a + c) \lambda = 0$
$ 2b\lambda = 0$
$ (2c+a)\lambda = 1$
$a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + ca - 1 = 0$

It is clear that $b = 0$. This is something we knew even before we set up these equations.

From first equation, $c = - 2a$ and from third equation, we get $ \displaystyle a = - \frac{1}{3\lambda}, c =  \frac{2}{3\lambda}$

Now if you plug values of $a, b, c$ in the constraint, you get two values of $\lambda$ and you can check which gives maximum $c \ (\gt 0)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I know this is a little late, but I just noticed that I am not quite getting the sentence "It is clear that b=0. This is something we knew even before we set up these equations." I've been thinking about it for a while and can't understand why is it clear even before the equations?

Comment: We need to maximize $z$. Simply put, it is because $x^2 + z^2 + xz = 1 - y^2$. To maximize LHS, $y$ should be zero but we cannot say the same for $x$ because we have $xz$ term and $x$ being negative or positive makes a difference.

Comment: Now if we think geometrically, this is equation of an ellipsoid which is symmetric to XZ plane as we have only $y^2$ term but it is not symmetric to XY and YZ planes. So max(z) will be in XZ plane but not at $x = 0$.